# how to show html code in android webview from php web service

Tags: php, android, html, json, textview

I have an android application that application takes data from my php json web service.  How can my php service give my json data to my android apk to show html content true. My android apk using textview to show my text content.

I used "`\n`" or "`<br>`" but its not working.

```
mysql $desc = 'satir1\nsatir2\n' ; 
//or $desc = 'satir1<br />satir2<br />' ;
$desc = trim(htmlspecialchars_decode($desc)) ; 
mysql insert into ........
```

Comment: Can you show your code

Comment: post your code within the question please

Comment: When insert to mysql
 $desc = 'satir1\nsatir2\n' ; //or  $desc = 'satir1<br />satir2<br />' ;
 $desc = trim(htmlspecialchars_decode($desc)) ;
 
 mysql insert into ........

Comment: HTML content or code to show android webview, I didn't get you.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you have to do is create a webview as follows 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Then use load the json content using the  loadDatawithBaseURL.. example
http://www.codota.com/android/methods/android.webkit.WebView/loadDataWithBaseURL